# react native mapbox use sdf icons

Tags: react-native, mapbox

I am trying to implement a SymbolLayer where the icons have some data driven colour. The docs state that one can achieve this using sdf icons, however I can't quite seem to find any resources on how this should be done in practice in react native mapbox gl.

The only examples I could find online are for the Mapbox gl js web library. If anyone could share some knowledge, that would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As of 8.0, sdf icons are not supported in `@react-native-mapbox-gl/maps` yet.

But 8.0 supports [Images#onImageMissing](https://github.com/react-native-mapbox-gl/maps/blob/master/docs/Images.md), which lets you generate images on the fly.